# Skype plugin muddling the assembly code

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skype plugin converts user reputation and badges to a phone number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128583/skype-plugin-converts-user-reputation-and-badges-to-a-phone-number)

When the Skype plugin is activated, it converts the register addresses in assembly language to Skype phone number. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11660366/863980), under update, 00391293 and 00391297 are converted to Skype Add-on call blocks (offering me to call Italy).

According to [this site](http://amdsoft.com/stop-skype-changing-my-website-design/), the following meta tag in template head would prevent Skype plugin to wrap the numbers on the entire page:

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

The [other method](http://www.ambrosite.com/blog/hide-phone-numbers-from-skype-using-the-html-soft-hyphen) with which users can prevent Skype to interfere is by planting soft-hyphen `&shy;` somewhere between first four digits. Unfortunately, ­ is not allowed in the code block.

[image: Skype muddling the SO posts]

Comment: Doesn't the plugin have a way to exclude sites and/or domains?

Comment: There are a few more ways here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448372/how-can-i-remove-skype-phone-number-recognition I've never got the meta tag to work, and editing the source HTML isn't gonna happen. The CSS solution from that post is pretty good. Real solution is to uninstall the stupid plugin and send bitter complaints to Skype.

Comment: @minitech, but there is no way to overcome this problem in `code block`. The question you suggested is not even mentioning the problem affecting the user input.

Comment: @JasonWilliams: It doesn't matter; we've established that the problem here is the Skype plugin, and they're not going to support it. (Recommendation: uninstall it, it's terrible and useless.)

Comment: @WesleyMurch, we cannot force everyone to uninstall the plugin. Since it does affects the readability of stackexchange viewers and there are number of ways (using CSS,JS,META-tag) to take care of it, then imo we can suggest the dev team to rescue this issue at application tier.. the way they feel best. Check out the answers on this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3746579/1493272

Comment: @JasonWilliams: I totally agree, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8089693/398242 The plugin came already loaded into IE9 on my new laptop which is how I became aware of it. I'm sure loads of people have it running and don't know what it is or how to disable it. I guess I was just saying that the plugin sucks, but I do think this is a legit issue - and definitely not limited to stack exchange sites.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: what's the intersection between the set of people who want to read disassembly of C functions and the set of people who don't know how to uninstall browser plugins?

Comment: This is entirely the Skype plugin's fault, and is not the problem of Stack Exchange. I think this question should be closed as off-topic, for the same reason as [the other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128583/skype-plugin-converts-user-reputation-and-badges-to-a-phone-number).

Comment: @Flexo: It's an IE-only plugin, which begs the question "why is an SO user on IE"? Probably because it's not their machine (library, work, etc.), and they can't install/uninstall programs at will. It's not SE's responsibility, but it's a problem for some people and it's possible to "fix it for them" with CSS/JS hacks if you decide to. I gotta say though, that screen shot it hilarious.