# Extra space after links

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I don't recall exactly when, but in the last few days an extra space started showing up after all links.  Does anyone know why?

I only see it in Chrome (on a Mac).  I don't see the extra space in Safari or Firefox.

In the screenshot below, note the extra space after "zlib" in the question and after "zlib manual" in the answer.

[image: shows extra spaces]

Comment: [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838699/how-can-i-decompress-a-gzip-stream-with-zlib) looks fine for me in Chrome on OS X. Also, its HTML is fine: `... algorithm as what <a href="http://www.zlib.net/">zlib</a> uses.` So: some extension installed in your Chrome? And if it's only on Stack Exchange sites: maybe some SE userscript?

Comment: It's something on your end. Either what @Arjan said or might also be malware hijacking links and changing them to something else so make sure the links are not corrupted.

Comment: Yes, it's only on stackexchange web sites.  I haven't seen it anywhere else.  I disabled the Avast Chrome extension, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 3):

It was caused by a combination of the [Avast](http://www.avast.com/en-us/index) extension to Chrome and something different about the stackexchange web sites.  I did not see this effect on any other web sites that I frequent.  When I removed the Avast extension to Chrome, the extra space went away.

A side note: the extra space did *not* appear on this meta stackoverflow site with the Avast extension.  This site seems to display links differently, with a finely dotted line under the link.

Comment: Do you know how to use developer tools in your browser? If so, you might be able to see *what* Avast was inserting into the HTML.

Comment: Yes, I could have.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to turn the extension back on.

Comment: Now you've got me curious.

Comment: I got it back.  I did a view source, and there was nothing inserted at the link.  It might be a style or javascript somewhere else that's doing it.  I tried a diff with the extension on and off, but way too many other things change between reloads of the page with no change in the extension state to sift through for my patience.  My curiosity has been defeated by my laziness.

Comment: I think it's something worth reporting in their support forums, lots of people are using Stack Overflow.

Comment: For extensions, view-source is not the way to go, as that will show you the plain HTML that has been received from the server. Instead (if you're still interested), right-click the link and select "Inspect Element", which will show you the HTML in its current state. (Including anything that has meanwhile been changed by JavaScript.)

Comment: Related: [Skype plugin converts user reputation and badges to a phone number](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128583/skype-plugin-converts-user-reputation-and-badges-to-a-phone-number) and above all: [Skype plugin muddling the assembly code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141189/skype-plugin-muddling-the-assembly-code) ;-)

Comment: Aha!  The extension inserts a tag: `<a href="http://www.zlib.net/" wrc_done="true">zlib</a>`, the `wrc_done` tag.