# How to add Skype id to Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)
>   [Skype plugin converts user reputation and badges to a phone number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128583/skype-plugin-converts-user-reputation-and-badges-to-a-phone-number)

Lately I've started noticing on Stack Overflow that if you hover over some users profile pictures it shows their Skype id, but when I try edit my profile I don't see any option to save this type of info, so how can I add my Skype id to my SO profile?

[image]

Comment: Really? Do you have a link to such an example profile?

Comment: @Deni - Please don't link like *3rd from the top* because the position can be changed withing a second. :)

Comment: This user -http://stackoverflow.com/users/238232/heather

Comment: I'm not sure what you're seeing, but I don't see any Skype ID. It's not this Skype browswer plugin going bonkers on some random numbers?

Comment: It's there bro just check hims056 answer

Comment: Github, Bitbucket, Twitter, Last.FM, Steam (no link)...I must be overlooking something then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is not a real Skype link. It is most likely a problem with the Skype browser plugin which thinks it has found a phone number. The user has:

4870 rep, 6 gold badges, 29 silver ones and 102 bronze.

This explains the "phone number" <strike>(4)</strike>870629102

Comment: Unfortunately SE doesn't seem interested at all in fixing it, but just blaming it on Skype. It's actually **not** Skype's fault.

Comment: @animuson I do indeed seem to remember an earlier discussion on the subject (years ago?). In any case, should the OP think it is Heather's number, then I'm afraid he's out of luck.

Comment: I linked it in the comments above. It's currently closed as "off topic."