# Why is there a Skype link around my reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation

I'm assuming this is a .css issue or some sort of bug that is mistakenly identifying my reputation as a phone number?

See the circled portion of the screenshot.

> [image]

Comment: That's definitely not SE's fault. Definitely.

Comment: You likely have the Skype plugin installed and it's mistakenly interpreting the text as a phone number (for whatever reason)

Comment: Closing, but this should be kept around.

Comment: Related: [Skype plugin converts user reputation and badges to a phone number](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128583/skype-plugin-converts-user-reputation-and-badges-to-a-phone-number)

Comment: next time use a freehand circle...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duh.  Disabled the Skype add-on for Internet Explorer.  Surprisingly, this resolved the issue for I.E. and Firefox.

Even though this was a boneheadedly-obvious thing to check, I'm going to keep this question out there in case others run across it.

Comment: I'm going to wait until my reputation is 8,675,309 then click on it and ask for Jenny.  See what happens.I should be about 203 years old by then, and nobody will get the reference.

Comment: I married a Jenny once, she was horrible.

Comment: I went to school with 27 [Jennifers](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jennifer).  16 Jenns, 10 Jennies, and then there was her... And you can see that song also has a very specific target audience age too.