# How can I prevent a large number from being displayed as a link?

Tags: support, markdown

I just [typed a large number](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/132503/1), each three digits being separated by periods.

Like so 1.020.000.000

This is rendered as a link. How can I prevent that?

Comment: FWIW, it's not displayed as a link in the iOS app,  mobile Safari, or mobile Chrome (which uses the same rendering engine as mobile Safari, I think?).

Comment: @DanBron Oh, it must be one of my extensions doing this. I tried it in Incognito Mode in Chrome (desktop) and it was no longer a link.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128583/skype-plugin-converts-user-reputation-and-badges-to-a-phone-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have an extension running that makes this links instead of just text. On all devices I have it shows correctly.

Some extensions, like Skype, try to make phone numbers out of numbers, or add advertisements on random text, this might be the case with you too.

Try to disable all extensions or take another browser and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. I have this extension that makes links clickable even if they arent <a> elements. I had totally forgotten about that extension, and my mind didn't connect the dots.

Comment: Ah, no problem. Glad this issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 3):

It was just [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickable-links/mgamelhnfokapndfdodnmfiningckjia). I had totally forgotten I had it, and didn't connect the dots.